# Skyscraper Lights selection for emissive shader

Tags: uv, light, lighting, emission

I'm working on some skyscraper using a PBR, but I was wondering if there is a way to select the faces that contains the windows with the lights on, and put an emissive shader; or if there's a way to select a specific color (yellow) to select where the emission should be. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you're using an image texture, in that case you could mix it with an *Emission* in a *Mix Shader*, and also use it as the factor of this *Mix Shader*, so that all the bright parts of the image become emissive (you could also use the *Emission* inputs of the *Principled BSDF* but you can more easily control the *Strength* of the *Emission* with the following setup):

[image]